# i am implementing deep linking for my android project in my xamarin forms in visual studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

acutally we have two project one is web and another is mobile application so i want whenver i click on the link it should give me option to open in my app.

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
    DataScheme = "https", DataHost = "skmtprod.johnsoncontrols.com", DataPathPrefix = "/", AutoVerify = true,
    Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable })]

[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
    DataScheme = "http", DataHost = "skmtprod.johnsoncontrols.com", DataPathPrefix = "/", AutoVerify = true,
    Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable })]
```

this is the link that i am accesing from a browser :-https://skmtprod.johnsoncontrols.com/Ticket
right now when i am accesing it is directly opening in a browser not giving a option to open in a app
please help me out?

i want it to work properly

Comment: Some browsers have a setting to allow URLs to be opened in Apps. Also did you create a `/well-known/assetlinks.json` file on the server to verify you links? This is a requirement from Android 12: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks